# Question seems impossible to answer but there are other ways to reach end goal. How should I comment or answer?

Tags: discussion

["Throttle" a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31148299/throttle-a-function)

This seems like a fair question but it also seems like the answer is, "That's nearly impossible."  Loosening up the title of of the question to "How do I reduce my CPU usage with this intense, multi-threaded computation?" would be a lot easier to answer, but in truth is a different question (by way of being much more vague).

Someone has already commented about thread priority is which is as close as you can get.  I'm wondering why this wasn't submitted as an answer and I don't want to steal answer.

I also think several other comments are possible answers, but don't directly address the title of the question.

I'm thinking of mentioning this:  (shortened)

> As mentioned by -x- Thread Priority is the only CPU throttling mechanism you have inside
>   the process.  It is not an app's responsibility to directly control CPU utilization, it is the OS and processor's responsibility.
>   However, you can break up the intense calculation into a
>   separate service (on another machine that can be load balanced or put
>   on a VM and CPU throttled that way) that does all the work and using
>   the async pattern to nearly eliminate that requesting machine's CPU
>   load and blocking for that operation.  (And that other service could
>   simply be a database stored proc or query where the database is on a
>   different machine).

I think this solves the heart of the problem and is useful to others trying to solve a similar problem.

So is my response a comment or answer or is it simply unacceptable? (Are the other comments really answers? )

Comment: That would be an answer, yes.

Comment: These are known as XY problems: asking about X when the real problem is Y, and they are not uncommon here. It's OK to answer Y and to state why X is impossible.

Comment: *However* you have to be extremely careful about the contrary issue: A huge problem on QA sites is when someone asks: "How do I ___ ?" and people answer "Oh, you *shouldn't do* ___, do this instead!" It's tricky.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When the OP is asking for something that can't really work, an answer explaining why not, along with a workaround is excellent!

So, yes, that is a (good) answer.